# how to show UIAlertController in a custom UITableViewCell in button click using swift code?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, xcode6

i want to show UIAlertController  in a custom UITableViewCell in a button click. but i can't find any way for this. please see the below code that i have try.
[image]

this code give error in UITableViewCel, that is shown in above picture.
please help me.the whole class code is below:

```
class CustomCellDeerCalls: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var detialsInfoButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var DeerCallNameLabel: UILabel!

var arrayOfDetialsInfoDeerCalls: [String]=["This sound is a doe's way of locating other deer of her family group . This call can be used all year long.",
"Grunts are a doe's way of saying come here , also to call her fawns at feeding time . It is critical to keep the call soft as a loud grunt is too aggressive of a call.",
"A buck grunt is a deeper pitch than a doe grunt , it means the same thing . The older the buck the deeper the tone. ",
"As the buck chases the doe as the rut approaches he is frustrated, and makes a series of soft grunts while trailing her. It's the bucks way of asking her to stop so he can be breed with her.",
"This sound's a lot like a calf bawl , but it is a series of buck bleats. This signals the bucks desire for company.",
"This is a non aggressive and social behaviour that all bucks do after shedding their velvet . This is when the bucks learn who can whip the other . This process does not prevent serious fights later on during the rut.",
"This is the sound that a buck makes during the courtship when the doe stops running , but won't let the buck breed her. It's a non aggressive and frustration call by him.",
"This is the sound that a Doe makes to signal that her breeding time is near.",
"This is the sound that a Doe makes to signal that she ready to breed RIGHT NOW.",
    "Deer make this sound to intimidate other deer and prevent fights. This call is often made by a rut- crazed buck when confronted with a rival. This sound can send smaller buck running from the area.",
"Another rut crazed Bucks sound to intimidate other deer and prevent fights when confronted with a rival. This sound can also send smaller buck running from the area.",
"This is a short aggressive rattling sequence to possibly lure in less aggressive, but curious buck, as well as the local dominant whitetail buck of the area. To make this sound like a real fight sniffs, wheezes and grunts have also been thrown in for added effect."]


var arrayOfDeerSoundsCall: [String]=["CONTACT","doegrunt","bkgrunt","tend","bawl","spar","rage","estrusb","bellow","sniff","wheeze","rattle"]
```

//  var arrayOfCallsName: [String]=[""]

```
@IBAction func clickDetialsInfoButton(sender: AnyObject) {

   var alert = UIAlertController(title: "dddddd", message: arrayOfDetialsInfoDeerCalls[sender.tag], preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //sender.sup
   //
}

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


@IBAction func clickplayButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    println(sender.tag)

    var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(arrayOfDeerSoundsCall[sender.tag], ofType: "wav")!)
    println(alertSound)

    // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()



}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
func setCell(callName: String){

self.DeerCallNameLabel.text=callName

}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i found a solution. following are code for above question. 
write the following code for button in viewcontroller where table view are present.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let deerNameCell: CustomCellDeerCalls = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCellDeerCalls
    let deercallcell=arrayOfCallsName[indexPath.row]

    deerNameCell.DeerCallNameLabel.text=deercallcell.callName
    deerNameCell.playButton.tag=indexPath.row
    deerNameCell.detialsInfoButton.tag=indexPath.row
    deerNameCell.detialsInfoButton.addTarget(self, action: "showAlert:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return deerNameCell

}
```

and the funtion for alert in the same view controller:

```
   func showAlert(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println(sender.tag)
    let deercallcell=arrayOfCallsName[sender.tag]
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: deercallcell.callName, message: arrayOfDetialsInfoDeerCalls[sender.tag], preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to call `presentViewController` on a `UITableViewCell` but this method is a member of a `UIViewController` instead.

Here is my suggestion:

1) Create a `CustomCellDeerCallsDelegate` protocol, ie.:

```
protocol CustomCellDeerCallsDelegate {
    func showAlert(title:String, message:String);
}
```

2) Add a weak property to your custom cell:

```
var delegate:CustomCellDeerCallsDelegate?
```

3) In your `clickDetialsInfoButton` function call a method on a delegate:

```
self.delegate?.showAlert("DDDDD", message: arrayOfDetialsInfoDeerCalls[sender.tag])
```

4) Add a protocol implementation to a ViewController that hosts the table view that displays the cell.

5) In a protocol implementation of `showAlert` function - show the alert:

```
func showAlert(title:String, message:String){
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "dddddd", message: arrayOfDetialsInfoDeerCalls[sender.tag], preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: i try this one but not working. alert is not shown on button click. thanks for answer.

Comment: @IbadUrRahman To make this work you should set your delegate:
6) in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function: `deerNameCell.delegate = self`